# How to place 3 d3.js charts in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

I want to place 3 d3 charts in a row I tried doing it using bootstrap fro html but it does not help id there a better way to do this

My current code

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4" id="chart_1">23</div>
  <div class="span4" id="chart_2">45</div>
  <div class="span4" id="chart_3">34</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r2qepmk0/3/

If I change bootstrap class to col-xs-4 which otherwise place divs in row but somehow the charts do not render.

js fiddle with the col-xs-4 class https://jsfiddle.net/r2qepmk0/4/

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your https://jsfiddle.net/r2qepmk0/5/ have a look.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="span4" id="chart_1">23</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="span4" id="chart_2">45</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="span4" id="chart_3">34</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Just in case if you want remove white space between columns you can [try this link](https://jsfiddle.net/r2qepmk0/6/)